# Render undefined in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why react crashes when it access `props` of `undefined` `cannot read property of undefined`

ex One: Knowing that props.name is undefined this code will return an error.

```
const component = (props) => {
         return(
             <p>{props.name}</p>
     )
  }
```

ex Two: Why in this case it is ok for `react` to render without errors `undefined` which in this case would return invisible.

```
const componentTwo = () => {
         return(
             <p>{undefined}</p>
     )
  }
```

Comment: You should not get an `cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error by writing `props.name`. If e.g. `props.person` is `undefined`, you will get that error if you write `props.person.name`.

Comment: Does  `props.person` is `undefined` means also `props.person.name` is also `undefined` ?

Comment: If there is no `person` property in the `props` object, `props.person` will give you `undefined`. Trying to access `name` on `undefined` will give the error `cannot read property 'name' of undefined`, because you can't access a property on `undefined`.

Comment: @Dodz, unsure if your question is answered or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing `props.name` should not give you the error `cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. If the `name` property doesn't exist on the `props` object, `props.name` will just be `undefined`.

However, if there is e.g. no `person` property on the `props` object, `props.person` will give you `undefined`. Trying to access `name` on `undefined` will then give rise to your error, because you can't access a property on `undefined`.

You could then use the `&&` operator to make sure `props.person` is set before using `props.person.name`.

**Example**

```
const MyComponent = props => {
  return <p>{props.person && props.person.name}</p>;
};
```

Also make sure that your component names start with an uppercase letter, or [the component will be interpreted as a string instead of as a variable when using it](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwEwlgbgfAUABHYBjA9gWwA4oHYFNsAucA9LAsAMLpZ6ElRwzDHjRA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=).

Comment: Tholle, while everything you write here is correct, I am unsure if it answers the question(?). I don't see anything about a `person.name` prop. Are we certain that is the case here?

Comment: @Chris No, you're right. There is no `person` prop explicitly mentioned in the question, hence I wrote `e.g.` after the discussion with Dodz in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, I assume that OP code is only a example snippet where it accidentally got a little bit *too* simplified ;) I would point out though that components should start with Capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not passing props to the component, then props will be `undefined`. If this is true (that you are passing no props), then trying to access `props.name` will throw that exact error! In order to ensure that props are given to the component, you can do as the other answer says, using the `&&` operator.

```
const MyComponent = props => {
  return <p>{props && props.name}</p>;
};
```

To answer the other part, React will render `{undefined}` because there is nothing to render. Just saying `undefined` isn't trying to access a property of undefined. Similar to if you had an object like

```
var myObject = undefined
```

and then tried to access a `name` property of this object:

```
console.log(myObject.name) //throws 'can not read property name of undefined'
```